# selecting data recursively from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for SQL Query where I can get data based on result. For example from table User i want to select top 10 records where user id is between 1 to 100. if there are only 5 records within that range i want to change the where clause id from 1 to 200 and if there are still less than 5 records i want to change the where clause again from Id 1 to 300. But i want to do that only till id is 500 or max 5 recursion. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
DECLARE @retval int   
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = Count(CS.Id) FROM user where id between 1 and 100';

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@PostCode INT, @retvalOUT int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition,@PostCode, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;

IF ((SELECT @retval AS [Count]) > 10)
    BEGIN
           SET @sSQL = N'SELECT TOP 10 FROM user where id between 1 and 100';
       EXEC sp_executesql @mainSQL, @mainParmDefinition,@PostCode, @TOP_REC;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
           --SOMETHING HERE WHICH NEEDS TO BE RECURSIVE
    END
```

Comment: You use 5 in your question, but 10 in your code.  I'm not sure how this is different that just getting the top 5 from id < 500 ordered by id.

Comment: If it is more than 10 I want to select first 10 records but if it less than 10 then i need to change the ids and select  top 10 again if result is more than 10

Comment: Why the need for recursion when iteration will do?

Comment: Iteration example will be great too..

Comment: I agree with paqogomez. It seems like what you want could be accomplished with just `select top 10 ... where id < 500`. If that's not the case then maybe you can give a higher level explanation of what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The ordering of an `id` (auto-generated value) is meaningless.  _Yes_, due to the way they're implemented, later ids have sequentially greater (or lower!) values - usually; depending on how transactions are structured, interleaved threads can end up putting greater ids in first.  This also ignores entities that have some sort of `createDate` that may be updated.  Hitting tables multiple times this way is usually a bad idea - what are you actually trying to accomplish?  Can you give us sample source data and desired output?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve. When user login to website they have postcode and I need to provide him a list of other user near his post code. For example if user post code is 100, I want to search other users within the 99 and 101, but if i don't get 10 records within this range. I need to change the code from 98 to 102. Now I can do this very easily in my server side code but I want to achieve this within one sql query(means in just one database hit)..

Comment: Assuming "post code" is something like a zip-code, you're **not** guaranteed that sequential zip-codes are near each other, or that nearby zip-codes are sequential.  Even in the case of a perfect grid, you'll end up with non-sequential neighboring codes.  Essentially, you want some form of distance query, or at least some way to tell what neighbors what.  We need sample source data and desired results.  I find it doubtful that your current direction will yield either performant or **correct** (/best) results - segmenting by _user_ is the wrong way to go.

Comment: "SELECT TOP 10 U.* FROM Users U WHERE U.PostCode BETWEEN 100 AND 105" ----if result is less than 10 then change the range so my sql should become "SELECT TOP 10 U.* FROM Users U WHERE U.PostCode BETWEEN 99 AND 106" and i want to do this for five time only...is it clear my friend..i cannot post sample data due to NDA agreement and that is why I am just giving an example

Comment: You could post anonymized data. What do these `postcode`s represent?  What makes you think that querying them in this fashion will give you correct results?  You _can_ do this in one query with a variation on a distance formula, but I'm not convinced that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return you 10 rows from your table where id between (1,100) or (1,200) and so on

```
declare @lastid  int
declare @resultCount int
set @resultcount=0
set @lastid=0;
while (@resultcount<10)
begin
    set @lastid=@lastid+100;
    insert into #ResultTable 
          select top (10-@resultCount) * from user where id between (1,@lastid)
    where user.id not in (select id from #resultTable)
    set @resultcount=(select count(*) from #ResultTable);
end
```

If you want that it was only 5 recursion, change `WHILE` clause to:

```
while (@resultcount<10 AND @lastid<=500)
```

`#ResultTable` must be declared before excecution this query.

Answer (score 1):

The description in the question is somewhat confusing but with some clues from the comments I think you could just rank the rows based on the range the ID falls in, then sort by that ranking value when selecting top 10 rows, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (10)
  ...  /* your columns */
FROM
  user
WHERE
  id BETWEEN 1 AND 500
ORDER BY
  (id - 1) / 100,  /* this will give you 0 for 1..100, 1 for 101..200 etc. */
  NEWID()          /* this is just a randomiser, remove it if you are happy
                      with IDs always starting from the beginning */
;
```